# On Planet Steam's FFG version there's a conflicting cost on Luxury Quarters cards, which one is correct?

Tags: untagged

I played Planet Steam yesterday for the first time and we noticed that the cost of Luxury Quarters on the Player Aid and rules doesn't match the cost that is on the card itself.

We used the 1 Quartz + 1 Ore because it seems to be harder to get than what's on the card (I don't remember exactly but I believe it's 1 Quartz + 1 Energy").

Can anyone confirm this?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a thread about this: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1013771/luxury-quarters-missprint-update-ffg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Board Game Geek thread on this that has some information that might help.

[BGG Thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1012472/luxury-quarters-cost-question)

> KAS @kneumann Jul 27, 2013 This is what used to be called a Deed of
> Ownership and it cost 1 ore and 1 quartz.